# why my array is undefined in my savetime function but running properly in other functions?

Tags: javascript

i m calling my save function and st_bookmark and ed_bookmark array donot show any data in my JSON stringfy function the array is undefined or uncaught type error occur

```
  <script>
            var check = true;
            var st_bookmark = new Array();
            var str_print = new Array();
            var end_print = new Array();
            var ed_bookmark = new Array();
            </script>
        <script>
            function save() {
                var link = "M7lc1UVf-VE";
                var bk_name = $('#bookmark_name').val();
                var bk_tags = $('#bookmark_tags').val();
                var bk_email = $('#bookmark_email').val();
                var user = '@Session["email"]';
                var t = st_bookmark.pop();
                var ss = ed_bookmark.pop();
                var data = 

({ name: bk_name, tags: bk_tags, email: bk_email, link: link, start_bookmark: st_bookmark, end_bookmark: ed_bookmark }); 
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("save_bookmark", "chopaal")',
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    data: { data: data },
                    success: function () {
                        window.alert('success!!');
                    }
                });

                var check = true;
                var st_bookmark = [];
                var str_print = [];
                var end_print = [];
                var ed_bookmark = [];
            }
            function starttime() {
                if (check == true) {

                    temp = player.getCurrentTime();
                    st_bookmark.push(temp);
                    str_print.push((temp / 60).toFixed(2));
                    document.getElementById("str_book").innerHTML = str_print;
                    check = false;
                } else {
                    window.alert("Please End The Previous Bookmark");
                }
            }

            function endtime() {
                if (check == false) {
                    temp = player.getCurrentTime();
                    ed_bookmark.push(temp);
                    end_print.push((temp / 60).toFixed(2));
                    document.getElementById("end_book").innerHTML = end_print;
                    check = true;
                } else {
                    window.alert("Please Add the Starting Bookmark");
                }
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: Looks like you are declaring them two times first as global variables, then as local variables in save. Comment declarations in save() then it should work

Comment: You are accessing the variables before they are initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable declarations are hoisted in JavaScript:

```
var data = {start_bookmark: st_bookmark};
var st_bookmark = [];
```

is equivalent to

```
var data;
var st_bookmark;
data = {start_bookmark: st_bookmark};
st_bookmark = [];
```

As you can see, `st_bookmark` is accessed *before* it got a value assignment, at which point its value is still `undefined`.

I guess what you really want is to access the variables with the same name that are declared globally. In that case, you should completely remove the declarations of these similarly named variables from `save`.

If you want to "reset" those variables after the Ajax call was successful, you need to move the assignment inside the `success` callback and remove the `var` keyword (so that the identifiers refer to the global variables):

```
success: function() {
    window.alert('success!!');
    check = true;
    st_bookmark = [];
    str_print = [];
    end_print = [];
    ed_bookmark = [];
}
```